# Subtraction of array elements in for loop (java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException)

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, indexoutofboundsexception, subtraction

I need to subtract:

(2 - 0) and (4 - 2).

I need this to find how many numbers are missing.
I'm just learning for the first time coding, and logically it seemed correct to me.

Code subtract as long as "n" is minor than "(statues[statues.length-1])" which is "4", so it should stop at "2".
So I can't understand why do I get this error:

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 3 out of bounds for length 3

Indeed, if I print "c" I can see the correct result, but obviously it keeps calculating as the error line is the "c" line.

I've changed the code to different versions and it worked, but depending on numbers in the array, something was going wrong.

public class MakeArrayConsecutive2 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] statues = {0, 2, 4};
    makeArrayConsecutive2(statues);

}

public static int makeArrayConsecutive2(int[] statues) {    
    Arrays.sort(statues);
    int count = 0;
    for (int n = statues[0]; n < statues[statues.length-1]; n++) {
            int c = statues[n + 1] - statues[n];
            System.out.println(c);
            if (c != 1) {
                count += c - 1;
            }           
    }
    System.out.println(count);
    return 0;

}
```

}

Comment: Your loop initializes n with 0 which is the first element of statues array and goes up to 3 exclusively which is the last element of your array but your your last index of your array is 2, that's why n + 1 got the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: Your array contains only 3 elements (valid indexes are from 0 through 2), your loop runs from 0 to 3, so you're getting outside array bounds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the main misconception here is about *how* to iterate over some structure in a for-loop. Here, you've written

```java
for (int n = statues[0]; n < statues[statues.length-1]; n++) {
    int c = statues[n + 1] - statues[n];
}
```

This is incorrect, because when you try to work with statues[statues[2]], you're effectively working with statues[4], which doesn't exist; you probably just want to reference statues[n]. The solution to this is to treat n as a regular integer which takes all values in the range `[0, statues.length - 1)`. This would look more like

```java
for (int n = 0; n < statues.length - 1; n++) {
    int c = statues[n + 1] - statues[n];
}
```

I hope this helps, and please let me know if I was interpreting your intentions incorrectly.

Comment: Thank's really a lot for your help. You didn't just give me the solution, but I got the explanation regarding iteration, which is now clear. It perfectly worked with all tests.